# Plot data points with connecting lines but which leave gaps

Tags: plot, gnuplot, transparency

I like following `linespoints` plotting style:
http://www.gnuplotting.org/join-data-points-with-non-continuous-lines/

However, I have encountered an issue when I plot several lines with this style:

[image: plot of data points with non-touching lines]

As you can see the second series of points blank-out also the first series (lines and points), what I don't want to happen.

Feature of gnuplot which makes this possible is `pointinterval` and `pointintervalbox`.

Documentation of gnuplot:

> A negative value of `pointinterval`, e.g. -N, means that point symbols
>   are drawn only for every Nth point, and that a box (actually circle)
>   behind each point symbol is blanked out by filling with the **background
>   color**. The command `set pointintervalbox` controls the radius of this
>   blanked-out region. It is a multiplier for the default radius, which
>   is equal to the point size.

http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/set-show.html#set-pointintervalbox

Since the doc says, fill with background color I was hoping using a **transparent** background the issue could be resolved, but it seems to be that the color white is used.

#### Gnuplot version

```
gnuplot> show version long

    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.0 patchlevel 0    last modified 2015-01-01 

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2015
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')
Compile options:
-READLINE  +LIBREADLINE  +HISTORY  
-BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY  +BINARY_DATA  
+GD_PNG  +GD_JPEG  +GD_TTF  +GD_GIF  +ANIMATION  
-USE_CWDRC  +HIDDEN3D_QUADTREE  
+DATASTRINGS  +HISTOGRAMS  +OBJECTS  +STRINGVARS  +MACROS  +THIN_SPLINES  +IMAGE  +USER_LINETYPES +STATS +EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS
```

#### Minimal Working Example (MWE):

`gnuplot-space-line-mark-style.gp`

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo transparent size 350,262 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'
show version
set output 'non-continuous_lines.png'
set border linewidth 1.5
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 pi -1 ps 1.5
set style line 2 lc rgb '#0020ad' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 pi -1 ps 1.5
set pointintervalbox 3
unset key
set ytics 1
set tics scale 0.75
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:4]
plot 'plotting_data1.dat' with linespoints ls 1,\
     'plotting_data2.dat' with linespoints ls 2
```

`plotting_data1.dat`

```
# X   Y
  1   2
  2   3
  3   2
  4   1
```

`plotting_data2.dat`

```
# X   Y
  1.2   2.4
  2   3.5
  3   2.5
  4   1.2
```

#### UPDATE

A working [`pgfplots`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) solution is given on [tex.stackoverflow.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194442/8917)

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid, there is no solution with gnuplot. Gnuplot plots each point twice, once with background color, once with the original color. If gnuplot would respect the background color being transparent, it also wouldn't hide the lines of one plot. To do it properly, one would have to change the gnuplot source the physically shorten the line segments, and not just overpaint them. So that would be something for a feature request.

Comment: @Christoph: Thanks for the comment. Do you happen to know a different plotting software which actually can do this? Using different transparent layers would be a possibility. I think pgfplots can do this.

Comment: No, don't know how to do it with pgfplots, or any other plotting software. The chances, that pgfplots can do this, are quite high, so you may try to ask at [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a lot with gnuplot. It's just a matter of how complicated you allow it to get.
You can realize the gap by a two step plotting. First: only `with points` and second: `with vectors` with somehwat shortened lines between the points. For this, you need to create a preliminary plot in order to get the gnuplot variables `GPVAL_...` and do a bit of geometry calculations. The parameter `pxGap` determines the line gap in pixels.

***Revised version:***
The previous version was only running for gnuplot 5.0.0 to 5.2.7. The following script now works additionally for gnuplot>=5.2.8. However, does not work (yet) with logarithmic scale.

The desired line gaps are given in pixels and independent of the terminal size and the graph scale. However, since it requires the size of the terminal and graph which are stored in `GPVAL_...`-variables which you only get *after* plotting, therefore the procedure unfortunately requires replotting.
I'm not sure whether this works for all terminals. I only tested on wxt and qt terminals.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### "linespoints" with gaps between lines and points
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
# X    Y
  0    3
  1    2
  1.5  1
  3    2
  4    1
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
   0    0
   1    0.9
   2    1.15
   2    2
   3    1
 3.9    0.9
EOD

set style line 1 pt 6 ps 3 lw 2 lc rgb "black"
set style line 2 pt 6 ps 3 lw 2 lc rgb "red"
set offsets 1,1,1,1

# preliminary plot to get variables GPVAL_...
plot $Data1 u 1:2 w lp ls 1, \
     $Data2 u 1:2 w lp ls 3

pxGap        = 18.      # gap in pixels, 6 pixels per 1 pointsize
Factor       = GPVAL_VERSION+real(GPVAL_PATCHLEVEL)/100<=5.27 ? \
               GPVAL_TERM eq "wxt" ? 20 : GPVAL_TERM eq "qt" ? 10 : 1 : 1
Rx           = (GPVAL_X_MAX-GPVAL_X_MIN)/(GPVAL_TERM_XMAX-GPVAL_TERM_XMIN)*Factor   # x ratio axes units to pixel units
Ry           = (GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN)/(GPVAL_TERM_YMAX-GPVAL_TERM_YMIN)*Factor   # y
xa2p(x)      = (x-GPVAL_X_MIN)/Rx + GPVAL_TERM_XMIN   # x axes coordinates to pixel coordinates
ya2p(y)      = (y-GPVAL_Y_MIN)/Ry + GPVAL_TERM_YMIN   # y
xp2a(x)      = (x-GPVAL_TERM_XMIN)*Rx + GPVAL_X_MIN   # x pixel coordinates to axes coordinates
yp2a(y)      = (y-GPVAL_TERM_YMIN)*Ry + GPVAL_Y_MIN   # y
angle(dx,dy) = dx==0 && dy==0 ? NaN : atan2(dy,dx)    # -180° to +180°, NaN if dx,dy==0
dxp(n)       = pxGap*cos(angle(xp1-xp0,yp1-yp0))
dyp(n)       = pxGap*sin(angle(xp1-xp0,yp1-yp0))

set key noautotitle

plot xp1=yp1=NaN, \
     $Data1 u (xp0=xp1,xp1=xa2p($1), yp0=yp1,yp1=ya2p($2), xp2a(xp0+dxp(0))):(yp2a(yp0+dyp(0))): \
         (xp2a(xp1-dxp(0)) - xp2a(xp0+dxp(0))):(yp2a(yp1-dyp(0)) - yp2a(yp0+dyp(0))) w vec nohead ls 1, \
     '' u 1:2 w p ls 1, \
     xp1=yp1=NaN, \
     $Data2 u (xp0=xp1,xp1=xa2p($1), yp0=yp1,yp1=ya2p($2), xp2a(xp0+dxp(0))):(yp2a(yp0+dyp(0))): \
         (xp2a(xp1-dxp(0)) - xp2a(xp0+dxp(0))):(yp2a(yp1-dyp(0)) - yp2a(yp0+dyp(0))) w vec nohead ls 2, \
     '' u 1:2 w p ls 2, 
### end of script
```

**Result:** (gap in pixels, independent of terminal size)

[image]

**Explanations:** (adapted to the new version, originally inserted by Hotschke)

- **Question:** Why is there the argument `(n)` for `dxp(n)`, `dyp(n)`?
  `n` is always `0` when `dxp(n)`,... are computed and is not used on the right hand side.
  **Answer:**
  To make them non constant-expressions. Alternatively, one could
  add `xp0, yp0, xp1, yp1` as variables, e.g. `dxp(xp0, yp0, xp1, yp1)`;  however, the
  compactness would be lost.
- **Question:** What does the `using` part in `plot $Data1 using (xp0=xp1,xp1=xa2p($1), yp0=yp1,yp1=ya2p($2), xp2a(xp0+dxp(0)))` mean?
  **Answer:**
  `(,)` is called a serial evaluation which is documented under the
  section *Expressions > Operator > Binary* in the gnuplot documentation
  (only  v4.4 or newer).
  Serial evaluation occurs only in parentheses and is guaranteed to
  proceed in left to right order. The value of the rightmost subexpression
  is returned.
  This is done here for the initialialization of `(xp0,yp0,xp1,yp1)` for the
  subsequent plot of the line segments as vectors.  It is irrelevant for
  the plotting of points.
- **Question:** How does this draw `N-1` segments/vectors for `N` points?
  **Answer:**
  Setting `xp1=NaN, yp1=NaN` when plotting points ensures that for the
  first data point the initial data point `(xp0,yp0)` is set to `(NaN,NaN)`
  which has the consequence that the evaluation of `dxp(0)` and `dyp(0)` also returns `NaN`.
  Gnuplot in general skips points with `NaN`, i.e. for the first
  data point no vector is drawn. The code draws the line between the
  first and second point when the iteration reaches the second point.
- **Question:** How does the second `plot '' u ...` iterates over all points?
  **Answer:**
  `gnuplot> h special-filenames` explains this:
  There are a few filenames that have a special meaning:  `''`, `'-'`, `'+'` and `'++'`.
  The empty filename `''` tells gnuplot to re-use the previous input file in the
  same plot command. So to plot two columns from the same input file:

  ```
              plot 'filename' using 1:2, '' using 1:3
  ```
- **Question:** Do we need the parentheses e.g. around `(yp2a(yp0+dyp(0)))`?
  **Answer:** `gnuplot> h using` explains this:
  Each  may be a simple column number that selects the value from one
  field of the input file, a string that matches a column label in the first
  line of a data set, an expression enclosed in parentheses, or a special
  function not enclosed in parentheses such as `xticlabels(2)`.

Comment: I had a few questions regarding your answer. I have added them to your answer with a preliminary answer by myself. If you find the time to check them out and correct them if necessary, this would be great. Thanks for your great answer. (Afaik, the style `with vectors` exists since [gnuplot 4.2](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main/ci/branch-4-2-stable/tree/NEWS).)

Comment: thank you for your edit. Well, I tried to keep it short. All your questions and are helping to better understand the code. Your answers are all fine. Yes, it was the compactness which I had in mind when creating functions like `L3(n)`which are actually independent of `n`.

Comment: one thing which could be maybe improved is the dependence of `L1` on the scale. Ideally, it should be the same visual gap independent of the absolute x- and y-range. Somehow related to the pointsize (in pixel- or screen units or whatever). Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: Indeed this could be improved. Unfortunately, I do not know a solution either. Ideally, the gap should scale with the point size and not the scale of the axes. And of course it should not be sensitive to the x- to y-range ratio. There are different coordinate systems in gnuplot. Afaik `show variables all` contains not a variable which could be used to calculate the offset in character units and then convert it to the coordinate system of the x- and y-axis.