# Gnuplot, draw several curves wih transparent pointintervalbox

Tags: plot, gnuplot

[image]

I'd like to make a figure like the one shown above in Gnuplot. With points and lines and a gap between the points and lines, but the pointintervalbox blocks the curve below. Id' like to have it transparent, so that if I have a point as an open square and a second curve crosses it I can see the curve as well

Comment: Where is your data and your script attempt? What have you tried so far? Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I guess you copied the image from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30297735/7295599) without referencing it. I would say the suggested solution there (although cumbersome) does exactly what you are asking. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way the plots are constructed, I don't think there is a complete solution for what you ask.  If the pointinterval box were transparent it would server no purpose - it only works because it is drawn in the background color. I can offer two partial solutions:

1. Reduce the size of the circular buffer zone drawn around each point, e.g. `set pointintervalbox 1.1`. Any value equal or bigger than the point size will allow you to draw empty point symbols.
2. Redraw the points (only) from the earlier plot after drawing the second plot. This will not prevent some overlap of the pointinterval box onto the line segments of the other plot, but it may help when the point symbols of one plot are very close to point symbols of the other plot. For this purpose you redraw the points with no backing box so no new overlap is created.

In the example here you can see several cases where line B is visible through a point on line A, which as I understand it is what you are asking for.

```
set style func linespoints
set pointintervalbox 1.5
set pointsize 1.5
set sample 200

plot sin(x) lt 1 lc "blue" pt 6 pi -5, sin(x)+.1 lt 2 pt 6 lc "purple" pi -5, \
     sin(x) lt nodraw lc "blue" pt 6  pi 5 notitle
~
```

[image]